# USB-C device (UFP) sourcing power?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c

I would like to design a device with an USB type C connector, USB2.0 only, no PD function, UFP data role but the power role is source only.

The device is a self-powered peripheral that sources energy to a phone (acts as a 5V 1.5/3A charger too) but occasionally could be connected to a USB-A host that does not need to be powered.

Is this configuration possible in the USB standard? Any suggestions for a USB power controller?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you just read the [USB Power Delivery documents](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-power-delivery) to find out?

Comment: definitely possible ... if I use a USB cable to connect my phone to my computer, then I see a popup dialog that asks `charge only or share data?`

Comment: asking `Any suggestions for a USB power controller?` is off topic here because it is unfocused, and it is a shopping question